# Stokes Theorem: conceptual question about the normal vector and the flux

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, vectors, vector-fields, stokes-theorem

The exercise that generates me a doubt is the following:

Let $F$ be the vector field given by $F= (xy+\sin(x^2), zy^2, xy)$

Calculate using a surface integral: $\int_c \vec F \ d\vec r$

$c$ is the intersection curve between $5x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and the plane $z+ \dfrac{y}{2}=1$

My doubt is that I got a negative flow and a normal vector that I interpret that points outward from the surface. I understand that this is not possible so I leave my resolution below and I thank if someone can correct me and help me to understand this concept if I wrong about it.

The intersection between $5x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and the plane $z+ \dfrac{y}{2}=1$ is $(2x)^2 +(y-2)^2 = \left( \dfrac{2}{5} \right)^2$ that is the domain of the parameterization

$$\varphi(r,\theta) = \left( \frac{r}{2} \cos \theta ,r \sin\theta + \frac{2}{5}, 1- \frac{r}{2} \sin \theta - \frac{1}{5}\right)$$

Then, the normal is: $ \vec N= \varphi_r \times  \varphi_\theta = \left(0,\dfrac{r}{8}, \dfrac{r}{4}\right)$ this normal vector points out of the surface

On the other hand  $ \nabla \times \vec F= (x-y^2,-y,-x$

Then, by Stokes Theorem $$\int_C \vec F \cdot \vec {dr} = \iint_S (\nabla \times \vec F) \cdot \vec {dS}=\iint_S (\nabla \times \vec F)(\varphi(r,\theta)) \cdot (\varphi_r \times  \varphi_\theta) \, dr \, d \theta = \dfrac{-2 \pi}{125}$$ This is a negative flux and and the normal vector I got points out of the surface.

Comment: Why do you want to use Stoke's theorem and not simply compute the circuitation? You also need to know in which direction the curve is travelled.

Comment: Because the exercise asks to calculate a line integral of a vector field using a surface integral of a vector field and Stokes is precisely that equality